Why does my Windows 11 laptop not boot unless it is exposed to sunlight?
I have an HP laptop EliteBook 850G5, brand new.
My laptop doesn't power on. Surprisingly, it works after exposure to sunlight for about 5 mins, every day. What might be the issue?
When I remove the battery and connect it directly to the power source it completely fails to boot.

have you tried shining a flashlight on the camera? I've had issues where my laptop will start booting, but the screen brightness is too low, because it has become confused and believes its in a very dark room, so it seems like its off. Just a quick thing to try.

Warmth will cause metal to expand. So I'm fairly sure that there's some loose contact inside somewhere.

"When I remove the battery and connect it directly to the power source it completely fails to boot." - Most laptops are designed to only function with a battery. Given the age of your laptop I am not suprised by the fact it does not work without a battery.

If the laptop is brand new, you should pursue replacement by the retailer or warranty service if you're outside the return window. This is not normal behavior, and I'm in agreement with LPChip that this most likely indicates a loose contact inside the laptop.

@music2myear It isn't brand new. You can find refurbished ones in Amazon, perhaps others, but the model has been discontinued years ago. It was based on 7th and 8th generations Intel CPUs, AFAIK.

We cannot tell you specifically why, because the problem is vague. However, based on physics and other things we can infer, the problem is most likely due to a poor connection inside the laptop.
Sunlight warms your laptop, and metal expands a bit as it warms. This leads us to believe the likely cause is that a connection is broken (open) when the laptop is cold, but comes back into contact (closes) as the laptop warms.
If the laptop is indeed "brand new" you should pursue replacement by the retailer, or, if it is outside the return window, you should pursue warranty service. If there is no warranty on the laptop and it is not, in fact, "brand new", you should take the computer to a competent local PC hardware technician for service as there is little chance we, with the information you have (or could) give, would be able to specifically note the parts that need to be inspected and/or replaced.
